# Fluency with forward plugin: how to add kubernetes metadata to logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, logback, fluentd, fluent-bit

Hey i have a question.

Im using logback-more-appenders(fluency plugin) to send logs to EFK stack (fluent-bit) which is working in kubernetes cluster, but it lacks kubernetes metadata ( like node/pod names).

I know i can use `<additionalField></additionalField>` in logbck.xml to add Service name (because this is static), but i cannot do it to dynamic parts like node or pod name.

I tried to do it on fluent-bit side using kubernetes filter, but this works only with tail/systemd inputs not a forward one (it parses tag with filename which contains namespce and pod name). Im using forward plugin to send logs from java software to elasticsearch, and in logback.xml i cannot enter dynamic pod name (or i don't know if i can).

Any tips how i can do it? I prefer to send logs using fluency instead of sniffing host container logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the best i could think of was to change from forward to tail plugin with structured logging (in json).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Pass POD ID and NODE NAME as environment variables in logback.xml as additional fields, that you can attribute the metadata to the logevents?

Comment: When i changed to tail plugin then i could add kubernetes filter and it appends metadata of node, pod, containers etc. Aditionally structure logging in JSON helped with parsing multiline stacktrace errors, because they are in single object.